# EF4 - How to enlist in existing transaction?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, transactions

I have a web application that uses asp.net mvc and I create my EF context in a base controller and have it available for the entirety of the request and then dispose the context when the base controller is disposed. I want to be able to enlist the context's connection into an existing transaction that was stored in the session.

Start a new transaction using:

```
ObjectContext context = new MyEntities(myConnectionString);
DbTransaction transaction = context.Connection.BeginTransaction();
```

And then store it in the current session:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["EFTransaction"] = transaction;
```

And then on a new request retrieve the transaction from the session and enlist the context:

```
context.Connection.EnlistTransaction(
(???)HttpContext.Current.Session["EFTransaction"]);
```

The only problem is I don't know what to cast (???) to. The `BeginTransaction()` method returns a `System.Data.Common.DbTransaction` object and `EnlistTransaction(System.Transactions.Transaction transaction)` requires a Transaction object.

My goal is to basically create and modify the same entities between requests and then commit all changes to the db when the user is ready to save them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really sure if this is the optimal approach, keeping a transaction open between multiple page requests, and storing in session would open a ratther long, and potentially uncommitted transaction, which would keep acquiring locks on your tables.

The best way to approach this might be to start a transaction just befoer you are ready to commit changes. There you can use TransactionScope like this ...

```
using (var tscope = new TransactionScope()
 {
  ..... all changes here ...
  tscope.Complete()
 }
```

you dont have to explicitly enrol any connection in the scope, any connection opened during the operation would automatically enroll, and if you have any open connections they would be closed and reopened with the transaction again.

if you are worried about concurrency issues, you can use timestamp based columns in your tables.

also let me add that EF uses transaction implicitly when save is called, an external scope is only necessary when multiple saves are required, or when the default transaction level (READ COMMITTED on Sql Server) is not sufficient.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because this is how you should handle transactions when using EF, do not store them in the session - see Ladislav's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Transaction stored in session? OMG ...

**Stop!** Storing transaction in session is terribly wrong idea. Go back to your analysis and change the architecture **now**.

Why? Suppose that your application is used by more than one user (yes it usually happens for ASP.NET apps). Now the first user stars data modification in your long running transaction. The transaction really communicates with the database and it uses **locks** on records. So after first uncommitted change the transaction locked some record. Now every query from other user / transaction which will try to access the same record will wait until the modification transaction is completed (unless you allow reading uncommitted data which is almost same as not using transactions at all). If modification transaction takes 10 minutes all other users accessing the same record will timeout.

It is just single example why it is completely wrong idea. There are more like including high probability of dead locks, performance issues on SQL server, transaction timeouts etc.

What is even worse your transaction is distributed so I somehow doubt that it can work because connections from all context instances used in the transaction must be alive when you decide to commit and until you commit they must not be disposed or reset (returned to connection pool).

This is done in completely different way:

Store objects in session and push them to database when user completes all changes - SaveChanges itself uses transaction so if you save changes together they will be in transaction and until user completes the changes there is no reason to save them. Be aware that this doesn't mean to store context in session!

Long running transactions really exists but they are "custom implemented". It means that data are persisted to database as without transaction and you have separate code called compensation which can revert changes. This is something you don't need in this scenario.

Comment: After thinking about this some more, I agree storing transactions in the session is an extremely bad idea. To update my entities I just need to call the ApplyCurrentValues() method on my entity set. Thanks for your help.